# What does executes first, method defined in action attribute of action Function or the javascript function in the name attribute?

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
<apex:actionFunction action="{!docReady}" name="funAtLast" reRender="form,alpha,table,button"/>
```

When I call funAtLast() function defined in my script on my VisualForce page then which one will execute first, docReady() of controller or the funAtLast() method of script?

Answer (score 2):

The name attribute on the [actionFunction](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm) identifies or defines the actionFunction as a javascript function with that name which you can call from anywhere else in the visualforce page.

The name attribute is not going to hold another JS method which will be called when the actionFunction is called. So there is no confusion in which runs first.

When you call the javascript function with that name defined in the actionFunction's name attribute from any of the allowed places in the VF page, then the related server side controller's method specified in the action attribute will be run.

Answer (score 1):

A bit more detail about all the available timings... let's add more parameters.

```
<apex:actionFunction action="{!docReady}" name="funAtLast" reRender="form" 
    onbeforedomupdate="beforeDom()" oncomplete="whenComplete()"  />
```

So, when JavaScript calls `funAtLast()`, it initiates the AJAX request. Notice the A stands for asynchronous. So if you have any other JS immediately after that function call, it will continue to execute even before the server has responded.

When the request completes, before it has rendered anything new, the JS function `beforeDom()` executes. Then the Visualforce element `form` is re-rendered according to the new view state of the Apex controller and its DOM element is replaced with the new content. Finally the JS function `whenComplete()` executes.

This can be useful to know if you want to provide visual feedback during the action cycle and/or prevent other actions from attempting to run at the same time.